# Alphanumeric data gets converted into a scientific notation while writing csv file in python

Tags: pandas, string, alphanumeric

In my data frame one column contains alphanumeric data. While checking the type of each that columns type is shown as string but some data in that column gets converted into a scientific notation while writing csv file in python.
For example, 12e34 gets converted into 1.20E+35.

I want the original data as string or text when I write a csv file or excel file.

Thanking You in advance for your time.

Code for example

```py
>>>df=pd.read_csv('test.csv')
>>>df

          Id
0     12E34
1     120PF
2      1875F
```

When I read the file the file, the code is shown correct as 12E34.  But after writing a csv file using to_csv if the open the saved file the ID 12E34 will get converted into scientific format as 1.20E+35.

While working in pandas I don't face any problem after saving output file I face this issue.

Comment: 1. show input dataframe . 
2. have you tried to change those values to string before save to csv?

Comment: Yes I tried to change the values to string using astype() function but still getting same problem

Comment: provide input dataframe , and your current code

Comment: if you are using pandas.read_csv to input your data, you can use dtype to set the data type of certain columns in pd.read_csv. eg. df = pd.read_csv("file_path", dtype={"name of column contains alphanumeric data":str})

Comment: I get problem after writing the csv or excel file. When I open csv or excel file that I have saved. I see some string data gets converted into a scientific format. Example 12e34 is shown as 1.20E+35

Comment: @Foram if so, it's irrelevant with the csv or excel file you saved. It's only because the software you used to open mis-transform the data to wrong data type. It's often seen in MicroSoft Excel. I think you can search how to import data and set data format in Excel or other software you use to open the saved file. Please read the method 3 in this article:https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/05/01/convert-csv-excel/#import-csv-wizard

Answer (score 0):

It's get converted during save, or rather when you read saved data again? If second, remember to set proper dtype.
If it's a save problem, try to set quoting to *csv.QUOTE_ALL*

Comment: No I don't face issue while reading the file. I get problem after writing the file in csv or excel file. When I open the csv file or excel file, I see that some strings gets converted into scientific format

Comment: Can you give us a code for sample dataframe to save and check?

Comment: I have edited my question and added code. Please help

Answer (score 0):

I use your code and example to run this part. As you said, It's okay while running pandas part. See below:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r"test.csv", index_col=0)
df.to_csv(r"test2.csv")
df

      Id
0  12E34
1  120PF
2  1875F
```

When using text editor, like **notepad or notepad++**, to open the saved file, the data is still 12E34. When using "smart" software, like **Excel and WPS**,  to open the saved file, the data would be 1.20E+35.(The reason that I say "smart" is Excel will infer the data type for each cell. So Excel infer 12E34 from str to  scientific notation of num)

So what does that mean? That means that the saved file is okay but the software you chose to open the file doesn't handle the type of data well.

Don't worry about your saved file. Your data is still in right format. It could be checked by using notepad. If you still want to use some "smart" software like Excel to open the file. Here is the suggestion: Please make sure the data type of the ID column is string while importing data into you software. If you are using Excel, please read the method 3 in this article https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/05/01/convert-csv-excel/#import-csv-wizard.

Comment: I will try this. Thank you